# How to determine if dialogflow source is text or audio?

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I want to distinguish my bot's Alexa and Google Home experience from text-based bots. Text-based bots support Rich Response types, but audio ones do not.

My problem is that I can't find a field in the Dialogflow V2beta1 API docs that specifies text source from audio. It looks like in V1 there was a [`message` field](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/agent/message-objects) that used a numeric enum to indicate this, but I can't find a V2Beta1 equivalent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Actions on Google, instead of checking the input type of the source query, you can check the [surface capabilties](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/surface-capabilities), which will allow you to see whether the device has a screen or not.